# How to set an event listener which closes the menu

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/discourse-plugin" version="0.8.13">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#daily-check-in').length) {
      $('#daily-check-in').attr("href", settings.daily_check_in_url);
      $('#daily-check-in').text(settings.daily_check_in_text);
    }

    if ($('#current-user').length) {
      var image_bell = 'https://cdn.ramseysolutions.net/church/fpu/images/icon-bell.svg';
      $('#current-user').find('img')[0].setAttribute('src', image_bell);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#js_fpu_global_nav > ul').css('transition', 'margin 0.4s').delay(1000);
    }, 2000);
    $('#js_top_nav_hamburger').click(function(e) {
      $('#js_fpu_global_nav > ul').toggleClass('open-top-nav');
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).is("#js_fpu_global_nav > ul") === false) {
        $('#js_fpu_global_nav > ul').removeClass('open-top-nav');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The important part is:

```
$('#js_top_nav_hamburger').click(function(e) {
  $('#js_fpu_global_nav > ul').toggleClass('open-top-nav');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

For now, when I move between pages in dynamic way, it keeps the menu open. I would like to close it every time user clicked on some other place of the page (not in the menu box) or if he moved to a different page (even if its from one of the links from this menu page).

I'm familiar with Vanilla JS `addEventListener` but I'm not sure how to use it here or if its the right approach. The desired output is to close the menu every time user clicks on something else. Other code could be found on Github ([link](https://github.com/lampo/discourse-financialpeace-theme/)).

Comment: `addEventListener()` is just like jQuery `.on()`. You don't need to use it if you're already comfortable with jQuery.

Comment: Just do `$('#js_fpu_global_nav > ul').removeClass('open-top-nav');` in the other actions that should close the menu.

Comment: @Barmer thanks for the reply. What do you mean by actions? I'm know very little about how JQuery works (I didn't write the code, just want to add my changes).

Comment: You have some code that does something when the user clicks on a link in the menu, right? Put that code in there so it closes the menu.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah but it does not handle the case where the user clicks on non-linked place somewhere else on the page. Also it does not handle the case where the user clicks a link not in the menu. So it should be something generic so I won't need to add this code in each link code.

Comment: Isn't that what your `$(document).on("click", ...)` does?

Comment: But if any of the other handlers use `event.stopPropagation()` the click won't bubble out to `document`, so you need to put code in those handlers.